# In the midasr package in r, how is the AR* model different than the AR model?

Tags: r, regression, autoregressive

At the end of the ?midas_r documention example what is the fourth parameter option in the mls() of the lagged dependent variable "*" doing that is different that the "regular" AR(1) model above?

I've searched through the documention and online and can't seem to arrive at an answer as to what it's doing exactly.

```
.
.
.
##Fit AR(1) model
mr_ar <- midas_r(y.ar ~ trend + mls(y.ar, 1, 1) +
             fmls(xx, 11, 12, nealmon),
             start = list(xx = rep(0, 3)))

##First order MIDAS-AR* restricted model
mr_arstar <-  midas_r(y.ar ~ trend + mls(y.ar, 1, 1, "*")
                 + fmls(xx, 11, 12, nealmon),
                 start = list(xx = rep(0, 3)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure I found out what it is.

It's the Smooth Transition Autoregressive (STAR) model.

Not entirely sure how this works within the MIDAS context and because the MIDAS documentation on this practically non-existent for this I can't read to discover what the midasr package is doing exactly.